# How solve Error HTTP 404.15

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json.net, asp.net-ajax

my problem is when i try to do a request in ajax, at the moment to send the information i got this error:

The Request Filtering module is configured to deny a request when the query string is too long.

i saw the problem is the huge cuantity of information that i send through the GET request. someone has the solution to solve this problem?

here i leave an example from the ajax and the controller that i use

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("nuevaTarjetaCapacitacion", "TarjetaCapacitacion")",
        scriptCharset: "iso-8859-1",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=iso-8859-1",
        data: {
            TarjetaCapacitacionId: $("#TarjetaCapacitacionId").val(),
            NombreCurso: $("#NombreCurso").val(),
            Descripcion: $("#Descripcion").val(),
            FechaInicio: $("#FechaInicio").val(),
            FechaFin: $("#FechaFin").val(),
            //TipoCurso: $("#TipoCurso").val(),
            Departamentos: tarjetaCapacitacion.Departamentos.toString(),
            Puestos: tarjetaCapacitacion.Puestos.toString(),
            Personal: tarjetaCapacitacion.Personal.toString(),
            Instructores: tarjetaCapacitacion.Instructores.toString(),
            InstructoresExternos: JSON.stringify(tarjetaCapacitacion.InstructoresExternos),
            Documentos: tarjetaCapacitacion.Documentos.toString(),
            AprobacionId: $("#AprobacionId").val()
        }


public JsonObject nuevaTarjetaCapacitacion(string NombreCurso, string Descripcion, string FechaInicio, string FechaFin, /*string TipoCurso,*/ string Departamentos, string Puestos, string Personal, string Instructores, string InstructoresExternos, string Documentos, int? AprobacionId)
    {
    }
```

Comment: How about combine all the parameters into one custom class and specify it as parameter. It would be more reasonable and readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a POST instead of a GET. 
That way the data will in the request body of the HTTP request and not in the query string.

Comment: but can i use post with the same parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Check here: https://forums.asp.net/t/2024846.aspx?HTTP+Error+404+15+query+url+too+long

The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.
Looking at the Requested URL I see this:

http://localhost:51358/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252F

It seems like a redirect loop somewhere. I suspect something in the IIS Express config but I have no idea what it could be (it's basically the

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("nuevaTarjetaCapacitacion", "TarjetaCapacitacion")",
            scriptCharset: "iso-8859-1",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=iso-8859-1",
            data: {
                TarjetaCapacitacionId: $("#TarjetaCapacitacionId").val(),
                NombreCurso: $("#NombreCurso").val(),
                Descripcion: $("#Descripcion").val(),
                FechaInicio: $("#FechaInicio").val(),
                FechaFin: $("#FechaFin").val(),
                //TipoCurso: $("#TipoCurso").val(),
                Departamentos: tarjetaCapacitacion.Departamentos.toString(),
                Puestos: tarjetaCapacitacion.Puestos.toString(),
                Personal: tarjetaCapacitacion.Personal.toString(),
                Instructores: tarjetaCapacitacion.Instructores.toString(),
                InstructoresExternos: JSON.stringify(tarjetaCapacitacion.InstructoresExternos),
                Documentos: tarjetaCapacitacion.Documentos.toString(),
                AprobacionId: $("#AprobacionId").val()
                   }
               });

 public JsonResult nuevaTarjetaCapacitacion(string NombreCurso, string Descripcion, string FechaInicio, string FechaFin, /*string TipoCurso,*/ string Departamentos, string Puestos, string Personal, string Instructores, string InstructoresExternos, string Documentos, int? AprobacionId)
        {
            Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        }
```

You should use `return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` instead of `return Json("")` otherwise you will get error "This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet."